# How to retrieve URL image from slide show website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I work on my senior project  and i need to retrieve one URL image from slide show contain a lot of photos from news slide show website .
can you help me please ?

Comment: Are you asking how to programmatically download an image from another website or are you asking how to make a slideshow with only URLs? Please be a little bit more specific with what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry ... I  need a library to download one image from slide show website .

Comment: or any other solution can perform that ...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you know the address of the file you wish to retreive, you can do something like this using the `WebClient` class:

```
string imagePath = "img\\cat.png";
using(WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.example.com/img/cat.png", imagePath);
}
```

The above example will download from `http://www.example.com/img/cat.png` and save the contents to the file path specified in the second parameter which in this case is `img\cat.png`.
Once loaded, in your ASP.NET code you could then have the path as the `src` such as:

```
<img src="img/cat.png" alt="Cat" />
```

Comment: thanks ..but the main problem is how i will take the ULR of any image form slide show website ..???

Comment: Is it your website that you're getting the images from?

Comment: No no .... any news website for Example BBC , CNN ......

Comment: Ah, I see. Just go to the website, right click on the image and view the source behind it to reveal the `src` or `background-image` URL.

Comment: hhh... i need a code , library or solution c# to use it in my project to perform that .....

Comment: Hi bro .....my problem is that how to read image slideshow URLs alone from a website ???